# Qt5.12 C++ How to dynamically load QPIxmap as texture in QML 3DScene

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qml

There is an application that displays a map in 2D (QGraphicScene) and 3D (QML 3D Scene) We need a map on 3DScene to dynamically display a map with a 2D Scene QML code, Loading occurs using QQuickImageProvider, which successfully works with Image in QML, but TextureLoader does not perceives.() Is there any simpler way, if not, how to solve this problem?

```
        id: scene3d
        Entity {
            Entity {
                id: floor

                components: [
                    PlaneMesh {
                        width: 10
                        height: 10
                        mirrored: true
                    },
                    TexturedMetalRoughMaterial {
                        id: material
                        baseColor:  TextureLoader {
                            id: textureLoader
                            source: "image://colors/yellow.png"
                            format: Texture.SRGB8_Alpha8
                            generateMipMaps: true
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcCy4.jpg)

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you use QtQuick3D you can use QtQuick 2D components such as Image by setting it to `Texture.sourceItem`, for instance:

```
            Model {
                source: "#Cube"
                materials: [
                    DefaultMaterial {
                        diffuseMap: Texture {
                            sourceItem: Rectangle {
                                width: 256
                                height: 256
                                color: "#78a"
                                Image {
                                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                                    width: 224
                                    height: 224
                                    source: "https://stephenquan.github.io/images/qt/madewithqt.png"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
```

You can see a sample of this by visiting https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/